# Read range chunks chunked with php

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I have an input field where I paste a download url.
After that, the I use an AJAX request to get the fileinfos such as headerinfo, content-length, mime type & in case I use curl accept-ranges.

I then start a consecutive loop of xhr2 requests with ranges to my php file.

```
http://www.example.com/chunks.php?url=http://url.com/someFile.ext&range=0-1024
http://www.example.com/chunks.php?url=http://url.com/someFile.ext&range=1024-2048
....
```

I can also change it to

```
http://www.example.com/chunks.php?url=http://url.com/someFile.ext&range=0-1024
http://www.example.com/chunks.php?url=http://url.com/someFile.ext&range=1025-2049
....
```

depending where my script starts to read the file.

My first approach was using cUrl & setting the ranges

```
<?php
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$_GET['url']);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RANGE,$_GET['range']);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

works great but if the range chunks are bigger than 1mb there is no animation on the client side `onprogress` event using ajax.

i prolly could use a custom `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION`... but i don't know how that works... so i changed approach and used the simple `fopen`

```
<?php
$r=explode('-',$_GET['range']);//get (from to) ranges
$cc=($r[1]-$r[0]); //Calculate Client Chunk length
$sc=128; //Set the Server chunk length

$b=""; //Buffer
$bytes=0; //bytes read

$h=fopen($_GET['url'],"rb"); // open the url
fseek($h,$r[0]); // jump to the from pointer retrieved from links

while($bytes<$cc){ //while bytes read is smaller than my client chunk
 $sc=(($bytes+$sc)>$cc?($cc-$bytes):$sc); //prolley an error here 
 //if the server chunk + bytes read is bigger than the client chunk
 //then the server chunk is clinet chunk - bytes read
 $b=fread($h,$sc); // read the buffer
 $bytes+=strlen($b); //add the buffer length to bytes read  
 echo $b;// echo the buffer
 ob_flush(); // flush 
 flush(); // flush
}
fclose($h); //close
?>
```

now this works ... I get the right animation on the client and also the final size is correct the pointers should be ok (0-1024,1024-2048) as I use fseek && fread.

but the file is corrupt.

Now after some tests ... this is very slow.

A better approach would be `cUrl` with `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` or `fsoket` open...

so I guess:

```
<?php
function $READ(){
 //here i need small chuncks of the response flushed. 
}
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$_GET['url']);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RANGE,$_GET['range']);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_READFUNCTION,$READ);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

If you have a better solution I'm open to everything that uses javascript and php.

The point of this is to create a download manager with resume that stores the file into the `window.webkitRequestFileSystem` without filling the memory of the browser.

Let's say the client has chunks of 8mb and the server chunks are 256kb ..

then every 8mb of the chunk is appended to a file previously created with `window.webkitRequestFileSystem`

and every 256kb I have an update of the average download speed and this way I can create a nice animation.

The php on the server uses only 256kb ram and the client browser can empty the garbage collection every 8mb (theoretically).

**EDIT2**

For this code I found a solution:

the code allows you to get ranges for example:0-100 
and get the output of this 100bytes chunked !!

**this allows you to have a AJAX script that has a continuos flawless PROGRESSBAR**

```
<?php
function w($ch,$chunk){ 
 echo $chunk;
 ob_flush();
 flush();
 return strlen($chunk);
};
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$_GET['url']);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RANGE,$_GET['range']);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,w);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

But I hope you guys have a better solution at all!! thanks

Comment: I bet the byte 1024 is doubled.

Comment: fseek($h,1024)-> points at 1024 & starts reading 1025... but i think it's better to use cUrl or fsoket..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get it to work with PHP curl's [`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` callback setting](http://php.net/function.curl_setopt). The following example callback function `curl_write_flush` intended for that curl option writes every chunk received and flushes the output to the browser.

```
<?php

/**
 * CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION which flushes the output buffer and the SAPI buffer.
 *
 * @param resource $curl_handle
 * @param string   $chunk
 */
function curl_write_flush($curl_handle, $chunk)
{ 
    echo $chunk;

    ob_flush(); // flush output buffer (Output Control configuration specific)
    flush();    // flush output body (SAPI specific)

    return strlen($chunk); // tell Curl there was output (if any).
};

$curl_handle = curl_init($_GET['url']);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RANGE, $_GET['range']);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'curl_write_flush');
curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

I tried with small files and big files and it works great but you can't set custom chunk size.

Download stream is the same speed as I can get with my ISP.

If you have anything better i'm open for any answer.

Comment: CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE:  The size of the buffer to use for each read. There is no guarantee this request will be fulfilled, however.

Comment: i mean there is a bounty of 100 pts... if you post a simple example based on my code you can get the bounty.the question "example...?" wasn't intended to be a bad thing.

Comment: anyway thx for your answer and for correcting my bad english.