# PHP curl download remote stream / chunked data

Tags: php, curl

I have audio files on a remote server that are streamed / chunked to the user. This all works great in the clients browser.

But when I try to download and save the files locally from another server using curl, it only seems to be able to download small files (less than 10mb) sucessfully, anything larger and it seems to only download the header.

I assume this is because of the chunking, so my question is how do I make curl download the larger (chunked) files?

With `wget` on the cli on linux this is as simple as :

```
wget -cO - https://example.com/track?id=460 > mytrack.mp3
```

This is the func I have written using curl in `PHP`, but like I say it's only downloading headers on large files :

```
private function downloadAudio($url, $fn){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $path = TEMP_DIR . $fn;
    $fp = fopen($path, 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: First, do you control the server, and if so, can you disable chunking conditionally? If so, I’d just do that and have PHP set some thing like a special header that you watch for. Otherwise, have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18081658/231316

Comment: So, the server is sending small chunks intended to be used in a player, right? In that case, you'll need to create one request for each chunk and merge them together manually. This "chunk approach" is common on streaming services to save bandwidth and track what parts of the video were watch.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. It turns out that it was the PHP memory limit on the origin server. I've only just configured this new machine and I forgot to change the default memory settings from 128M - which is why it was failing. All works as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was failing as I had forgotten to increase the default PHP `memory_limit` on the origin server.

It turned out after posting this question that it was actually successfully downloading any files that seemed to be below the 100mb mark, not 10mb as I had stated in the question. As soon as I realised this I checked the `memory_limit` and low and behold it was set to the default 128m.

I hadn't noticed any problems client side as it was being chunked, but when the server tried to grab an entire 300mb file in less than 1 second the memory limit must have been reached.